# Having trouble searching a string

Tags: php

Okay I have a csv file that gets parsed and displayed. I want to make it searchable. So I have a form that accepts a user query and compares it to the array to find matches. Now here's what I have:

```
foreach( $last as $key=>$string ) {
   $hits[$key] = strpos( strtolower( $string . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $middle[$key] ), $query );
}
```

Before this little snippet I force `$query` to lower also.

So basically this concatenates the full name, Last First Middle, and searches each array item for a match. Then if `$hits[$key] != false` I can say that there was a match there. So I go back and display that result from the main array of names. Hopefully that makes sense...

Now on the plus side, I will get many results that should show up. Like if I search `jo`, a list will come up with all of the Johnson last names.

The issue I'm having is results turning up that don't match the query or results not showing up when I know they are in the list of names. So I'll know `smith john` should return a result, but it will come back with no results.

This is the first time I've really worked on something with a search functionality so I want to do it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function returns the index of matched substring, meaning it could possibly return `0`:

```
strpos('foo', 'f'); // 0
```

If the substring is not found, it will return `FALSE`.

```
strpos('foo', 'z'); // FALSE
```

Because both `0` and `FALSE` are *falsy* values (meaning they both evaluate to boolean `FALSE`), you will need to use strict checking:

```
foreach( $last as $key=>$string ) {
   $hits[$key] = strpos( strtolower( $string . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $middle[$key] ), $query ) !== FALSE;
}
```

Notice the `strpos(...) !== FALSE` instead of just `strpos(...)`.

**Edit (for @baudday):**

Code:

```
<?php
$query = strtolower('Michael');

$last = array('Baier', 'Baker', 'Baker', 'Banfield', 'Banks', 'Barber');
$first = array('Michael', 'Michael', 'Stephanie', 'Christopher', 'Joseph', 'David');
$middle = array('Joseph', 'Daniel', 'Nicole', 'Phillip', 'Andrew', 'Daniel');

foreach ( $last as $key=>$string ) {
    $haystack = $string . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $middle[$key] . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $middle[$key] . " " . $last[$key] . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $string . " " . $middle[$key];
    $hits[$key] = strpos( strtolower( $haystack ), $query ) !== false;
}

foreach ($hits as $key => $matches) {
    if ($matches) {
        echo $last[$key] . ', ' . $first[$key] . ' ' . $middle[$key] . ' (key: ' . $key . ") matches the query.\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Baier, Michael Joseph (key: 0) matches the query.
Baker, Michael Daniel (key: 1) matches the query.
```

Comment: Hey awesome! So this alleviates the problem of results not showing up when I know they're there. The other problem is still occurring. I search for a name and I get results that don't contain anything even close to the query.

Comment: @baudday: I would need an example search term and example data that you're searching against to tell you why it's doing that.

Comment: Okay try these names formatted Last, First Middle: Baier, Michael Joseph; Baker, Michael Daniel; Baker, Stephanie Nicole; Banfield Christopher Phillip; Banks, Joseph Andrew; Barber, David Daniel;

Now search for Michael in that list. It should return that entire list. Will post my search code in a separate comment.

Comment: foreach( $last as $key=>$string ) {
            $haystack = $string . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $middle[$key] . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $middle[$key] . " " . $last[$key] . " " . $first[$key] . " " . $string . " " . $middle[$key];
            $hits[$key] = strpos( strtolower( $haystack ), $query ) !== false;
         }

Comment: @baudday: It seems to work okay for me.  I've edited my answer to show what code I'm testing with and the output.

Comment: Hmm, then it must be a different part of my code. I appreciate your help, and will mark this as the answer! Thanks again!